# what's the meaning of "in the spirit of Hegel"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

I want to know what "in the spirit of Hegel" means. What does it mean in the context of philosophy

I tried spirit but it didn't help me understand.

Comment: A full sentence, please.

Comment: Since "Spirit" (Ger *Geist*) is a central technical term in Hegel's philosophy we need a specific context to know whether the author means that technical term or something like more like "with an attitude like that Hegel displays".

Comment: Consider the closely-related injunction that people should observe [*the spirit of the law*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+spirit+of+the+law%22+%2B%22letter%22), not *the letter of the law* (do what the law **intends** you to do, ignoring any flaws in how that law was actually expressed in words).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question would be clearer with a full quote.

Generally speaking, "in the spirit of Hegel" means "*in line with*", "*according to*". It could refer to a number of things that fall under Hegelianism, such as Hegelian dialectics, absolute idealism, Hegelian logic.